# Delphi, FastMM - Block has been modified after being freed - Need help interpreting this FastMM report

Tags: delphi, memory-management, delphi-2007, fastmm

My app is reporting this error on exit when I run it from the IDE. I usually get one FastMM snag for each instance of a thread that was created while the program was running, but it's not repeatable enough to characterise this behaviour. Problem is I can't make any sense of the report.

```
---------------------------
APP.exe: Memory Error Detected
---------------------------
FastMM has detected an error during a free block scan operation. FastMM detected that a block has been modified after being freed.

The previous block size was: 40

Stack trace of when this block was previously allocated (return addresses):
403052 [APPHardwareDeclarations.pas][System][System.@GetMem][645]
405F0D [UFlxNumberFormat.pas][System][System.@NewAnsiString][956]
4065E1 [APPGlobalDeclarations.pas][System][System.@LStrSetLength][3356]
411AF7 [madStrings][madStrings.WideToAnsiEx]
41ACE8 [madTools][madTools.FindModule]
720074 [RpRenderCanvas][RpRenderCanvas.TRvRenderCanvas.FloodFill]
720074 [RpRenderCanvas][RpRenderCanvas.TRvRenderCanvas.FloodFill]
780065 [UXlsReferences][UXlsReferences.TReferences.SaveToStream]
4AAB2E [ExtCtrls][ExtCtrls.TTimer.Timer]

Stack trace of when the block was previously freed (return addresses):
405E59 [APPSendEmailSMTPQueue.pas][System][System.@LStrClr][494]
406DD3 [APPGlobalDeclarations.pas][System][System.@FinalizeArray][3584]
406D5D [APPGlobalDeclarations.pas][System][System.@FinalizeRecord][3560]
406E38 [APPGlobalDeclarations.pas][System][System.@FinalizeArray][3602]
47B6F2 [Classes][Classes.TStringList.Destroy]
404DFF [GIFImage.pas][System][System.TObject.Free][12891]
468741 [SysUtils][SysUtils.FreeAndNil]
506600 [StringUtilities][StringUtilities.AddCommaTextPair]
85C738 [APPLogWebTransactionsQueue][APPLogWebTransactionsQueue.ServiceWebTransactionQueue]

The current stack trace leading to this error (return addresses):
40D04C [FastMM4][FastMM4.CheckBlocksOnShutdown]
40DE88 [FastMM4][FastMM4.Finalization]
4059F3 [GraphicEx.pas][System][System.FinalizeUnits][8123]
458CAA [madExcept][madExcept.InterceptFinalizeUnits]
405CCB [IdCoderXXE.pas][System][System.@Halt0][85]
924868
7C90DCBA [ZwSetInformationThread]
7C81776F [RegisterWaitForInputIdle]
7C817778 [RegisterWaitForInputIdle]

Current memory dump of 256 bytes starting at pointer address 16902788:
6C 6A 95 00 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80
80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 D7 D8 6F E9 80 80 80 80 80 80 00 00 41 1E 90 16 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 52 30 40 00 9B 4D 40 00 11 82 40 00 62 51 40 00 E2 5B 64 00 21 76 64 00 68 77 64 00
12 B0 64 00 AD D6 64 00 6E 30 40 00 B9 4D 40 00 AD 51 40 00 6A 5C 64 00 78 82 40 00 78 35 64 00
83 81 40 00 48 6E 40 00 5D 6D 40 00 28 00 00 00 04 44 64 00 C0 27 90 16 6C 6A 95 00 80 80 80 80
80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80
3F D8 6F E9 80 80 80 80 00 00 00 00 40 FF 8F 16 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 52 30 40 00
0D 5F 40 00 E1 65 40 00 F7 1A 41 00 E8 AC 41 00 74 00 72 00 74 00 72 00 65 00 78 00 2E AB 4A 00
l  j  •  .  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €
€  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  ×  Ø  o  é  €  €  €  €  €  €  .  .  A  .    .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
.  .  .  .  R  0  @  .  ›  M  @  .  .  ‚  @  .  b  Q  @  .  â  [  d  .  !  v  d  .  h  w  d  .
.  °  d  .  ­  Ö  d  .  n  0  @  .  ¹  M  @  .  ­  Q  @  .  j  \  d  .  x  ‚  @  .  x  5  d  .
ƒ    @  .  H  n  @  .  ]  m  @  .  (  .  .  .  .  D  d  .  À  '    .  l  j  •  .  €  €  €  €
€  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €
?  Ø  o  é  €  €  €  €  .  .  .  .  @  ÿ    .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  R  0  @  .
.  _  @  .  á  e  @  .  ÷  .  A  .  è  ¬  A  .  t  .  r  .  t  .  r  .  e  .  x  .  .  «  J  .
```

Take the stack trace of when the item was previously freed.

```
468741 [SysUtils][SysUtils.FreeAndNil]
506600 [StringUtilities][StringUtilities.AddCommaTextPair]
85C738 [APPLogWebTransactionsQueue][APPLogWebTransactionsQueue.ServiceWebTransactionQueue]
```

is all sensible, but the next line:
    404DFF [GIFImage.pas][System][System.TObject.Free][12891]
puzzles me. I would expect Free to be called at this point, but what is `GIFImage.pas` doing in there? The trace for when the block was previously allocated is completely random. None of the items make sense.
I get the feeling something is not right with the FastMM setup, or FastMM is getting the stack traces from trashed memory.

I originally had this problem after compiling with Delphi 2006.  A completely new installation of Delphi 2007 has the same behaviour. Can anyone tell me what's going on?
TIA
R

Comment: Out of curiosity. Does the same happen if you remove madExcept from your project ?

Comment: What's happening is that you have freed a block of memory, and then accessed it later.

Comment: I realise that - my issue is that the dump FastMM has supplied doesn't give me any sensible information I might use to find out why.

Comment: Data breakpoint could help

Comment: @David - do you mean a break on value? - what variable?  I don't have any information on that.  There is nothing in the memory dump that gives me a clue as to what the memory was allocated to.

Comment: @TLama - bingo! removing MadExcept from the project also eliminates the FastMM errors on app exit.  Maybe I should cross-post to Madshi's forum ;)

Comment: I don't know what exactly madExcept internally does, but I wouldn't be surprised if some of the hooks would confuse FastMM the way you've shown. And don't hesitate to cross post this problem on their forum since it should not happen and can lead just to the improvement :-)

Comment: @TLama - I have [done that](http://forum.madshi.net/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=27640&p=46742#p46740) and received a couple of suggestions from Mathias.

Answer (score 1):

There can be some stack trace errors(like incorrect unit name, or some completely incorrect line, you should look more general on entire stack trace and skip incorrect individual lines)

I guess you don't fully understand this error.
Fast MM only detects that some block of freed memory was modified (it is detecting this on application exit, but not at the moment of block modification)

Stack traces in this case just show you when block was allocated and deallocated **but not when it was modified**.
Hunting for this type of error is very hard, you will have to find where memory is corrupted , you can use FastMM builtin procedure to check memory integrity (put a call to it everywhere after most suspicious memory operations) and good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I appreciate what FastMM reports, and that it works (I assume) by filling memory with a known pattern when it is freed and inspecting it later to if any bytes have been modified.  I would have a much better chance of finding the bug if the stack traces were meaningful.